# or condition in while loop in python with in operator

Tags: python, list, while-loop, in-operator

```
 def we():

    t="s"
    r=list(range(0,2))
   # here condition is if LHS equal to RHS then while loop will be run 
    while t.isdigit()==False or int(t) in r==False:
         t=input("enter element here")
         #digit check
         if t.isdigit()==False:
            print("enter element is not a digit")
         if t.isdigit():
            if int(t) in r:
              pass
            else:
               print("inuput element range should be between 0 to 2")
               
    return int(t)
```

`so in this i need to take input from the user. input should be digit from selected range from r.
it check the input element is string or digit but it does not check that the digit is in the range of r and the while loop get closed
basically it check only 1st condition in while loop it's not cheking 2nd condition.

`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why do you think it's only checking the first condition?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: it's working perfectly fine. Enter 5, and the message with "between 0 to 2" (sic) shows. Enter 1, and nothing shows, and the function exits.

Comment: You edit the second condition to ```if t.isdigit():
            while int(t) not in r:
                print("input element range should be between 0 to 2")
                break```

Comment: if i enter any digit in input then it directly return that digit it's not checkin second condition in while loop which was digit should be between range of 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the condition as:

```
while not t.isdigit() or int(t) not in r:
```

I think the problem is that you are comparing if `int(t)` is in `r==False`

Comment: I believe the PEP8 form is `int(t) not in r` when checking for a false membership

Comment: why int(t) in r==False: is not working

Comment: @TejasTeke It is evaluating as `int(t) in (r == False)` as the boolean operation evaluates before the in operation. As such it is equivalent to `int(t) in False` which is always False. Instead `int(t) not in r` will use the correct order.